# Why look ahead is returning matches for time-stamp

Tags: python, regex

Trying to write a script in python for some post processing. I have a file that contains messages with a time-stamp. I want to extract all the messages into a list.
 
Regex - start from message until next time-stamp.

```
findallItems = re.findall(r'(?s)((?<=message).*?(?=((\d{4})\-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))|\Z)))', fileread)
```

This works fine but it also returns time-stamps as matches. How can I only return the message and not include time-stamps ?

If I use look ahead position as text then it works fine. For e.g

```
findallItems = re.findall(r'(?s)((?<=message).*?(?=message|\Z))',fileread)
```

Comment: Provide the sample input messages you are parsing and the desired outputs. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Example input would be very useful so we can help you.

Comment: Change capturing groups inside lookahead to non-capturing groups `(?:...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove unnecessary capturing parentheses and convert others to non-capturing:

```
findallItems = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=message).*?(?=(?:\d{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|\Z))', fileread)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE7iF1/1)

However, you may just keep 1 capturing group over your necessary pattern and `re.findall` will only return this group value:

```
(?s)message(.*?)(?:\d{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|\Z)
           ^   ^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE7iF1/2)

Comment: quick and working answer definitely deserves an upvote :)